# AttributeError: 'English' object has no attribute 'vocal'

Tags: python, spacy

Im running this code with en_core_web_sm 2.2.5

```
>>> import spacy
>>> nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm', parser=False)
>>> print(nlp.vocal[u'fun'].similarity(nlp.vocal[u'humour']))
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    AttributeError: 'English' object has no attribute 'vocal'

Comment: Seems that npl is a "English" object, and does not have the vocal attribute. Run dir(nlp) to check the attributes available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I think you meant `vocab` instead of `vocal`.

Second of all, you are trying to access the word-vector and `vocab` has nothing to do with that.

Finally, you are using the `en_core_web_sm` model which doesn't support word-vectors according to spaCy official documentation [here](https://spacy.io/models/en).

My suggestion is to use `en_core_web_md` instead. You can download it using the following command:

```
python -m spacy download en_core_web_md
```

And you can change your code to be:

```
>>> import spacy

>>> nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_md', parser=False)
>>> nlp.(u'fun').similarity(nlp(u'humour'))
0.43595678034197044
```